# Как программно определить количество ядер в процессоре?

Tags: c++, linux

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите, как в C/C++ программно определить количество ядер в процессоре? Может метод какой есть?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numCPU = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    cout << numCPU << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Отредактировано:* Раз нашел, то сделал перевод [аналогичного вопроса на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150971/116546).

- **Linux, Solaris, AIX, OS X >= 10.4:**

  ```
  sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
  ```

  Или прочитать в `/proc/cpuinfo` (для LSB-совместимых дистрибутивов).
- **FreeBSD, OS X/Darwin, NetBSD, OpenBSD и их *BSD-сородичи:**

  ```
  int mib[4] = {CTL_HW, HW_AVAILCPU, 0, 0};
  size_t len = sizeof(numCPU);
  sysctl(mib, 2, &numCPU, &len, NULL, 0);
  if (numCPU < 0) {
      mib[1] = HW_NCPU;
      sysctl(mib, 2, &numCPU, &len, NULL, 0);
  }
  ```
- **HPUX:**

  ```
  mpctl(MPC_GETNUMSPUS, NULL, NULL)
  ```
- **IRIX:**

  ```
  sysconf(_SC_NPROC_ONLN)
  ```
- **OS X >= 10.5 (на Objective-C):**

  ```
  NSUInteger a = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processorCount];
  NSUInteger b = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] activeProcessorCount];
  ```
- **Windows**

  ```
  SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
  GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);

  numCPU = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
  ```

Comment: Спасибо, в шапку кинул, мб кому пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

Есть же кроссплатформенное решение в boost-е и в новом стандарте:

```
{boost,std}::thread::hardware_concurrency()
```

Правда им разрешается возвращать 0, если по каким-то причинам библиотека не может (или не хочет) определять число ядер, и gcc4.6 под Linux так и делает (видимо просто не реализовано). Но в то же время boost-овая версия выдает правильное число. Сейчас попробовал под Mac Os X, gcc4.7 – все правильно показывают и boost и std версия.